# Chess Knight problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Which is the number of all possible combinations of the knights, which are not mutually attack?

[image]

- The black knight may move to any of eight squares (black dots).
- The white knight in this case is limited to two squares (white dots).

we can use 1 and more knights bot we must be careful that other knights is not attacked.

```
If we take only 1 knight there is 64 possibilities.
If we take 2 knight there is much more combinations.
...
```

All knights are the same colour.
What is sum of all possibilities and how can we calculated it?

Comment: Place the black knight first.  In some of the 64 locations, this leaves eight forbidden squares (as pictured).  In others, it leaves two, or three, or four, or six forbidden squares.

Comment: Perhaps these links can help: [mathematical chess problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_chess_problem) and [knights problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnightsProblem.html).

Comment: You can have up to 32 knights not attacking, (though more than 20 is impossible in a real game of chess)

Answer (score 1):

Following up on vadim123's comment, there are $16$ positions from which the black knight can attack $8$ squares, another $16$ from which it can attack $6$ squares, $20$ from which it can attack $4$ squares, $8$ from which it can attack $3$ squares, and $4$ (the corners) from which it can attack just $2$ squares.  This gives a total of

$$16(64-9)+16(64-7)+20(64-5)+8(64-4)+4(64-3)$$

ways to place the black and white knights on different squares so as not to attack one another.  (If you don't distinguish the knights, then divide by $2$.)  This number is easy to calculate.

If the OP's "..." means keep going, with a *third* knight, then a *fourth*, etc., the calculation becomes MUCH harder.  I'm not even going to attempt it unless the OP indicates that's actually what he wants (and possibly not even then...).

Comment: if i got knight on corner i got two attacked fields and one field occupied 4(64-2-1)

Comment: @LukaToni, oh gosh, you're right.  I'll edit accordingly.